# Excel VBA Make Cell Active in a Specified Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure why the following code gives a "Not found" Message when the value in the initial active cell (-15.0) is also a value within the specified range.

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Double
Dim srchRng As Range
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    c = ActiveCell.Select
    Set srchRng = .Range("V17:V37").Find(what:=c)
    If srchRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Note sometimes a value of 0 exists within the specified range. If so I don't need to do anything but if 0 does not exist, I first need to find the least negative value (I use separately within the worksheet `=MAX(IF(V17:V37<=0,V17:V37),MIN(V17:V37))` and this becomes my initial active cell value [eg -15.0] to look for in the specified range), and this least negative value will then be set to zero (by using a goal seek function in this cell)

So this macro will ultimately incorporate an `If` statement or conditional `lookup`

Any feedback appreciated.

I made suggested changes but revised code below still returns "Not found".
Cell V38 has the value -15.0 but this number does appear in the range V17:V37.
This simple macro should result in the cell in the range corresponding to the c value being selected. Any further help appreciated.

```
Dim c As Double
Dim srchRng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reel_Pack")
c = Range("V38")
Set srchRng = .Range("V17:V37").Find(what:=c)
If srchRng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
End If
End With
End Sub
```

I found the following code to do the above.

```
    Dim c As Double
    c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V58").Value
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V17:V57")
        With cel
            If .Value = c Then
                .Select
            End If
        End With
    Next cel
    End Sub
```

But can someone suggest please how to improve this by actually incorporating the equation I have in cell V58 within this macro? As mentioned that equation is `=MAX(IF(V17:V37<=0,V17:V37),MIN(V17:V37))`.

So the macro would look into the range V17:V37 and if there is an exact zero then Do Nothing otherwise locate the cell with the least negative number (which is what the equation above does) and select that cell.

Comment: Use `c = ActiveCell` rather than `c = ActiveCell.Select`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook's point is absolutely correct, don't `Select` the `ActiveCell`. I'd go a step further and say change `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName")` And if your function `=MAX(IF...` is in a specific range (e.g. "V16"), refer to that range directly instead of using `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Something to consider - are they definitely the same number?  Is one _-15.0_ and the other _-15.01_.  Also it's worth setting some of the other `FIND` parameters: `LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole`.  [The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the correct reason:

`c = ActiveCell.Select` is returning the value `-1` which equates to `TRUE` in VBA.

So, *I think*, the line is asking the question `c = ActiveCell is Selected?` which returns a boolean TRUE/FALSE converted to a double which equals -1.

`c = ActiveCell` returns the default property of the `ActiveCell` which is `Value`.

So that line should read `c = ActiveCell` or `c = ActiveCell.Value` rather than `c = ActiveCell.Select`.

**Edit:**
Not so sure of my reasoning now - `c= Range("A1").Select` selects cell A1 and returns -1 still.
I guess that why you should avoid `Select` like the plague unless you want to actually select a cell rather than just reference it.  Have a read of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Darren many thanks. Neither of the two changes to the line you mentioned made a difference. I had played with that beforehand.